# keystonejs docker-compose restarting a server when file changes

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, keystonejs

I am using Keystonejs and docker-compose when I push a new file changes to my webapp. How to apply the changes?

```
docker-compose up
```

will restart the server without applying the changes.

What I do is remove my web app image and fire docker-compose up again. But this will do npm install again. Which takes a long time. Is there a way to apply small change like html change without firing npm install from within Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you share your docker-compose.yml file

Try the steps in this order:

1. If the code is on local host, are you using volume to share it with docker container? If no, please try that first. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes
2. If sharing folder (volume) doesn't work, try tools like https://github.com/remy/nodemon -- according to their website "nodemon is a tool that helps develop node.js based applications by automatically restarting the node application when file changes in the directory are detected."

Answer (score 0):

Old question and no docker-compose.yml provided by the original question, but almost 99% sure that the problem is solved using the build flag on docker-compose

```
docker-compose up --build
```

this will force to rebuild the image and fix the original statement :

> "What I do is remove my web app image and fire docker-compose up again"

with some luck depending on your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml it will cache npm install and also fix

> But this will do npm install again. Which takes a long time.

I hope this helps anyone facing the same issue